# Forcing to show grub boot menu always

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub, hibernate

In Ubuntu I have the following weird issue: I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu on /dev/sda7. I set up grub to automatically boot Windows 10. *Additionally* I am accessing the system via VirtualBox when I am running Windows. So I get the best of both worlds.
When I have Ubuntu running from within the VirtualBox and I put my Windows 10 to hibernation, grub *does not show the boot menu* on the next boot (when it should automatically boot back to Windows 10!).

**Observation:** Grub in Ubuntu does not always show its boot menu. It seems that when the system is in hibernation, it directly boots into Linux and does not show the boot menu.

**Assumption:** There must be some "flag" that tells grub that the system is booted (in VirtualBox) such that at the next boot (which happens on the actual machine), it automatically selects to boot Ubuntu to boot.

**Question(s):** Is there anything that prevents grub from showing its boot menu, for example, if the system is "running" or in hibernation? What causes this behavior and how can it be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of the boot loader - be it GRUB or anything else. The boot loader just passes the boot device to the kernel, it has no concept of whether that boot device is mounted.

The main point is, that hibernating a VM host (of any kind) creates a situation in which not all of the components have all the relevant information when they wake up.

You need to

- either hibernate the guest before you hibernate the host
- or "misconfigure" your bootloader so that it can't boot without human intervention. Mind: This is a workaround, not the intended use of the bootloader.

Comment: But it must be a “matter of the boot loader”. If it would not be, grub would always show me exactly the same boot loader, no matter if I shut down the system properly or not! The fact that it does not, implies that something in Ubuntu tells grub to not show the menu but rather boot to the last booted Linux config, without presenting any other option.

Comment: @divB The fact that the boot devices is **mounted** is not a matter of the boot loader - it knows nothing about that.

Comment: Something else knows that the boot device is mounted and changed the configuration of the boot loader accordingly (directly or indirectly). This is what I am talking about. Again, grub is not showing me its boot menu every time the machine boots! All I want is to prevent this and enforce always the same grub config. I am not saying this has to be purely grub but it can be some other script/package.

Comment: I think my question was confusing: It's not necessarily an isolated grub question but a system (Ubuntu?) question.I have updated the question to make it (hopefully) more clear.